# Twitter Bootstrap responsive CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a feature for my responsive website. It consists of an image carousel which contains a caption. On desktop, I am displaying the caption absolutely. The `div`, which contains a header and paragraph, is positioned on top of the image and takes up a width of 40%.

When the user is using a tablet or mobile I would like to display the caption relatively with a width of 100%. This makes the text appear under the image which is more suitable on the smaller screen sizes.

The two ways of doing this would be to duplicate the code with different css classes - one relative with the `visible-desktop` class and the other absolute div with the class `hidden-desktop`. The other way is to use javascript to toggle a class.

I was thinking, it would be great if I could achieve the above using purely css. Something like `.desktop .carousel-caption {` Is this at all possible.

Comment: You could maybe just use media queries and enter your different code in the relevant media query. Bootstrap's media queries are detailed here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: Oh! Excellent!! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe just use media queries and enter your different code in the relevant media query. Bootstrap's media queries are detailed here

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive